# ldapsearch from root succeeds, but doesn't succeed when base is not root

Tags: openldap, ldap

I have a ou which looks like this

```
ou=abcd,ou=ou1,ou=ou2,dc=mydomain,dc=com
```

The ou has a property called 'l' which has a value pqrs.

I do the following search

```
ldapsearch -x -b "dc=mydomain,dc=com" "l=pqrs"
```

This finds the ou.

However if I search

```
ldapsearch -x -b "ou=ou2,dc=mydomain,dc=com" "l=pqrs"
```

the ou is not found.

What is the reason for this? What am I doing wrong. This is openldap on linux

Answer (score 1):

Either you have problems with the permissions (you did not show us your `slapd.conf`), or you have made some modifications to indexing and have not yet run `slapindex`.

Comment: I don't administer this ldap server. Can you tell me what should I look for in slapd.conf for permission issues? Also how do I run slapindex - is it just slapindex without any params?

Comment: I think "l" is an attribute of mydomain.com but not for ou1 nor ou2.mydomain.com.